# What's wrong with my CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates

http://geodit.com:8000/d/8172

How come when I zoom-in using Chrome browser, and then move around, my black header (with the login and signup) gets cut off?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the black header that cut off, but it's the main div (with doc_leftcol and doc_rightcol) is the same size(you specified 960px) when resizing. But your header & footer is 100% width, so it's resized along with the body.

If you intend that your main div has fixed width, I recommend that you specified the fixed width for body too (or a div which contains all your page)